# Connecting Visual Studio 2010 to Team Forge

Tags: visual-studio-2010

How can I get checkout, checkin, change tracking abilities is VS for projects stored in Team Forge?

I have installed CollabNet's Integration apps with AnkhSVN and also Tortoise but in VS I don't see the usual SVN right-click options: checkin, checkout, etc or file change tracking

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the project in Solution Explorer and select "Add Selected Projects to Subversion"